# Import RIS from zotero to Mendeley while maintaining folder structure

Tags: citations, reference-managers

I am trying to export my Zotero library and importing into Mendeley. However, I would like to preserve the folder structure. I cannot seem to do it. Is this possible?

Comment: Does Zotero export folders as RIS entries?